# Pixel art software for Windows 10

Tags: software-recommendation, windows, pixel-art, games, free

I am into game design and I want to make my game in pixel art style. I saw a program called *Graphics Gale*. Is it good for pixel art?

Can anyone recommend some open-source, or free, Windows 10 pixel art software?

Additionally I'm looking for software that can also help me with the animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is [MagicaVoxel](https://ephtracy.github.io/)

It's an 8-bit voxel modeling and animating program that's free and open-source.

[image]

The software is still in its infancy but there are a small amount of tutorials showing how to [create scenes](https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/guides/building-with-magicavoxel.html) and [animate them](http://drinkdecaf.com/magicavoxel_animate).

[image]

### Other options:

There's also a large list of other free programs [here](https://lospec.com/pixel-art-software-list).

Notable other options are [Aseprite](https://www.aseprite.org/faq/) which is free if you [compile it yourself](https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite) and [GraphicsGale](https://graphicsgale.com/us/) which is also free.

Aseprite's compiling instructions are included in the install and can be reviewed [on it's github page](https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

Comment: I really like this program, but it is for *voxel* graphics. The OP wants to do *pixel* graphics.

Comment: You can make it pixel as well you just have a depth of 1 for the art "field".

Comment: I have upvoted it for now if the program is really what I need I will count it as an answer

Comment: @AhmedYasir You can you just have to adjust the "art field" settings to a depth of 1 rather than having it be a 3D space. There's also a large list of other free programs here: https://lospec.com/pixel-art-software-list.

Comment: @AhmedYasir Thanks, I've updated my answer with more resources.

Comment: Your new recourses are great I have counted your post as an answer

Answer (score 2):

I really like [Aseprite](https://www.aseprite.org/). It is not free though (unless you compile it yourself). It costs about $15.

For at free alternative you could try [Piskel](https://www.piskelapp.com/), which runs in the browser. Also a good program, but a little annoying that you need to export and import files instead of just saving and loading.

Comment: This is incorrect. It's free if you compile it yourself, see my answer.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor, ok I didn't realize that. This might be a bit too advanced for many users though.

Comment: I'd recommend GraphicsGale over Piskel.

Comment: There's a comprehensive walkthrough that comes with the source code on how to install it FYI. https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Comment: @Ovaryraptor, cool! I like free stuff, but in this case I also wanted to support the developer.

Comment: That's fine but the poster was asking for **free** resources.

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered [Piskel](https://www.piskelapp.com/), which is free and Open Source. You can make animations in it, and it has a web client if you want to access it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Stardew Valley developer concernedApe [has said](https://community.playstarbound.com/threads/game-development-and-engine-decision.25210/) that he drew that game's pixel art in [Paint.net](https://www.getpaint.net/). It works on Win10 and is free to use too (you can pay extra for getting it on the windows store, but you don't have to).

It doesn't have any animation-specific features, but seeing what Stardew has achieved, it's defintely possible to do great graphics in it.

Incidentally, concernedApe recommends [this site](http://pixeljoint.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=11299) for people wanting to get into pixel art. On programs, it has to say:

> There are plenty of good programs out there for pixel art, many of which are free. I use Grafx2, but GraphicsGale, Pro Motion, Photoshop, Pixen, and MS Paint are all common choices. Some are more user friendly than others, which is why I choose something with keyboard shortcuts like Grafx2 over MS Paint, it has saved me many trips to the toolbar (and makes for much easier palette  management).

Answer (score 0):

Krita I think is very nice to work I am using it on Ubuntu, but they have Windows version as well. you should try it. Many tutorials can be found on YT so very easy way to start working with it.